# How can I render data in a table using Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am trying to figure out how to render some data in a table using Handlebars.

I already have the part for the header.
I did it like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        {{#each chart.table-header}}
            <th>
                {{#if th-image.length}}
                    <p><img src="/assets/images/{{th-image}}" alt=""></p>
                {{/if}}
                <strong>{{{th-title}}}</strong>
                <p>{{{th-description}}}</p>
            </th>
        {{/each }}
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And here my chart.json:

```
{
    "table-header" : [
      {
        "th-title": "",
        "th-description": "",
        "th-image": "",
        "special-case": ""
      },
      {
        "th-title": "Online Investing",
        "th-description": "Make more informed...",
        "th-image": "MESDicon.png",
        "special-case": ""
      },
      {
        "th-title": "Merrill Edge Guided Investing",
        "th-description": "Go online to...",
        "th-image": "MEGIicon.png",
        "special-case": ""
      },
      {
        "th-title": "Invest with an advisor",
        "th-description": "Get professional...",
        "th-image": "MEACicon.png",
        "special-case": ""
      }
    ],

    "table-body" : [
      {
          // HERE GOES THE INFO FOR THE TBODY ELEMENT.
      }
    ]
}
```

But for the rest of `tbody` part I don't know how can I render the rest of the info.
It should look like this:

*But the idea is to render that data coming from the chart.json file.*

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
        <td>Investing method</td>
        <td>Online</td>
        <td>Online with professional portfolio management</td>
        <td>With an advisor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Simple, straight-forward pricing</td>
        <td><strong>$6.95 online equity & ETF trades<sup>3</sup></strong><br>(Qualify for $0 trades with Preferred Rewards)<sup>2</sup> Other fees may apply<sup>3</sup> </td>
        <td><strong>0.45% annual fee</strong><br>Other fees may apply</td>
        <td><strong>0.85% annual program fee</strong><br>Other fees may apply</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Minimum investment</td>
        <td><strong>None</strong></td>
        <td><strong>$5,000</strong></td>
        <td><strong>$20,000</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Investment choices</td>
        <td><strong>Full range of investments</strong></td>
        <td><strong>A set of ETF strategies</strong></td>
        <td><strong>A set of mutual fund/ETF strategies</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bank & invest with one login</td>
        <td>&#10003;</td>
        <td>&#10003;</td>
        <td>&#10003;</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this way 

{{#each array}}
  {{@index}}
{{/each}}

Comment: @KaushikThanki I know that. My issue is the logic of the table. How handlebars accommodate the data. Can you elaborate a bit more your answer? please

Answer (score 0):

since your table-body is array of objects. you can loop through that and using keys you can access data.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        {{#each chart.table-header}}
            <th>
                {{#if th-image.length}}
                    <p><img src="/assets/images/{{th-image}}" alt=""></p>
                {{/if}}
                <strong>{{{th-title}}}</strong>
                <p>{{{th-description}}}</p>
            </th>
        {{/each }}
    </tr>
</thead>

  <tbody>

   {{#each chart.table-body}}

      <tr>
       <td>{{this.your_key}}</td>
       <td>{{this.your_key}}</td>
       <td>{{this.your_key}}</td>
       <td>{{this.your_key}}</td>
      </<tr>

   {{/each}}

</tbody>
```

Comment: Ok Dinesh, Gilfoyle here. But, how does my json should look like?

Comment: that is up to you. ex: table-body:[{td_data1:"data1",td_data2:"data2",td_data3:"data3",td_data4:"data4"}..etc]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet to resolve the issue:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        {{#each table-header}}
            <th>
                {{#if th-image.length}}
                    <p><img src="/assets/images/{{th-image}}" alt=""></p>
                {{/if}}
                <strong>{{th-title}}</strong>
                <p>{{th-description}}</p>
            </th>
        {{/each }}
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    {{#each table-body}}
        <tr>
             <td>{{key1}}</td>
             <td>{{key2}}</td>
             <td>{{key3}}</td>
             <td>{{key4}}</td>
        </<tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: But, how does my json should look like?

Comment: {"table-header": [{"th-title": ......}], "table-body": [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2".....}]}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not enclosing your handlebars in a `<script>` tag. Handlebars will compile the template incorrectly without throwing any errors. For `div` it works always it seems.

Thus simply wrap the template section in a `script` tag like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="carBladeTemplate">
{{#each cars}}    
    <tr class="carItem" data-car-id="{{Id}}">
        <td>{{Id}}</td>
        <td>{{Make}}</td>
        <td>{{Model}}</td>
    </tr>                   
{{/each}}
</script>
```